# ePub.js - can't open certain books

Tags: html, angularjs, epub, epub.js, readiumjs

I am trying to run ePub.js on my local system using Node.js and NPM and getting issues while trying to open the ePub files.

In a very basic setup, I am using their existing example of Moby-dick book at `/Users/<username>/Dev/epubj.s/reader/index.html`. I am extracting the existing ePub books using an unzip utility to expose the `META-INF`, `OEBPS`, `mimeType` and other relevant files inside of it. After that, I modify the `index.html` file to replace `moby-dick/` to whatever the new ePub's folder is

```
window.reader = ePubReader("moby-dick/");
```

I run a series of ePub testing files, and get errors like:

this: 
[image]
this: 
[image]
this: 
[image]
this:
[image]
 and this:
[image]

One of the files that I used to test this is: 
[Moby Dick Test Copy](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2q8fgmfmeax4gx0/mobydick_soft_Hyphen.epub?dl=0)

Is there a limitation to the kind of ePub files ePub.js can open? Please note that all these ePub files otherwise open on other readers like iBooks or Adobe Digital Editions.

On a side note, I would like to know if ePub.js has an active community for some sort of dev support. Also, some testimonials or popular products made using ePub.js as their reader will also point me to a good place to get further support.